# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'disable_autoreload'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-pico

im trying to disable auto update in Circutpython 8.0 beta on the pico W and every time I run

`import supervisor supervisor.disable_autoreload()`

I always get this error

`>>> supervisor.disable_autoreload() Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'disable_autoreload'`
how can I fix this

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I'm not sure why because this function is still in the official documentation. Anyways, this worked for me on en_US-8.0.0-rc.2.

```
supervisor.runtime.autoreload = False
```